# Why don't in-app visits count for "Consecutive days visited"?

Tags: discussion, ios-app

On the week-end I seldomly use my computer and thus do not log in to Mathematics Stack Exchange from a browser. I do, however, use the (iOS) app to check for new questions or notifications on the weekends every day. Yet, my "Consecutive days visited" counter is always reduced to 1 after the week ends. It seems that in-app visits to Mathematics Stack Exchange do not count as actual visits to the site. Why is that so? Is this a bug or was this implemented on purpose?

Comment: Related post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Last seen not updating when using Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191781). (See also [the linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/191781).)

Comment: This belongs on Meta SE. Maths SE can do, and knows as a system, nothing about it.

Comment: @Nij Sorry, I was not aware of that! Thank you for pointing it out to me!